# Adding a Gradle Task for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

I have added the following the task to my build.gradle.

```
task runJcer {
    group 'Welcome'
    description 'Produces a greeting'

    doLast {
        println 'Tony mac chops in the house'
    }
}
```

However, I don't see it in the Gradle Tasks view in Eclipse.  Even after I do: Gradle / Refresh Gradle Project.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: On the right site of the tab panel should be a refresh button called *Refresh Tasks for All Projects*. Did you try to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Click the little button with the label "`Refresh Tasks for all Projects`" in the upper right corner of the `Gradle Tasks` view.